# jQuery: Sortable: Placeholder when list is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

What I would like to do is have a placeholder appear that is the same as the regular placeholder than comes up when I hover over areas I would like to drop a draggable, but only when the list is empty, and there is no draggable being dragged onto it.

This is how I have my current placeholder (for when hovering):

```
placeholder: {
        element: function(event, ui) {
            return $('<li class="module-drop-content brochure">Drop Content Here</li>');
        },
        update: function() {
            return;
        }
    },....
```

Incase that doesn't make sense here is a step by step of what I would like to happen:

1. User clears sortable of 'li's
2. Placeholder appears saying 'drop content here'
3. User hovers item over sortable once again, and the placeholder from step 2 is removed, in place of the regular hover placeholder.

I have tried many different methods and none seem to work in this situation.

Cheers

Comment: Did you find the solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are clearing list with some button you can make it also place your "Drop content here" placeholder in empty list. As for removing your placeholder use either [`beforeStop` or `stop` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-activate).